# scrollviewer with the textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have a textbox which is contained in a scrollviewer as below:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer" Height="200" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Width="500" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When I input a large number of data in the textbox, the scrollviewer will not scroll down automatically, so this lead I couldn't see what I'm inputing now in the textbox, I have to scroll down manully and see the content which I am inputting. I have two questions:

1. How to let the scrollbar automatically scroll down follow the line which I am writing now.
2. TextBox has a border, but if I scroll down, the top border will disappear, it looks like the text box is scroll up, how to make the textbox not changes, the 4 borders always appear and only the content wrapped?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use a ScrollViewer, or can you use the TextBox's own scrolling behaviour?
This behaves as you would want in normal Silverlight apps (can't test it on a windows 8 app right atm)

E.G.

```
<TextBox
    Height="200"
    Width="500"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

(Note that you don't seem to be able to set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and VerticalScrollBarVisibility properties from a Style)